# Why do I need to reload nginx if the webserver was down when nginx started?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-container

I have a docker container with nginx which has in the configuration:

```
proxy_pass http://web:3000; # rails app started with unicorn
```

If I start the nginx container and after that the web container, I need to do:

```
docker exec nginx_container_id nginx -s reload
```

Whis is this necessary? And why after I start the web container the nginx wont serve my app straight away?

Comment: Post your nginx container dockerfile.

Comment: you can check your nginx config with command: nginx -t